# New line in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using an procedure to Select First-name and Last-name

```
declare 
    @firstName nvarchar(50),
    @lastName nvarchar(50),
    @text nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @text = 'First Name : ' + @firstName + ' Second Name : ' + @lastName
```

The `@text`  Value will be sent to my mail But the Firstname and Lastname comes in single line. i just need to show the Lastname in Second line

O/P **First Name : Taylor Last Name : Swift** ,
 I need the output like this below format

```
First Name : Taylor 
Last Name : Swift
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use `CHAR(13)` -

```
DECLARE 
      @firstName NVARCHAR(50) = '11'
    , @lastName NVARCHAR(50) = '22'
    , @text NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @text = 
    'First Name : ' + @firstName + 
    CHAR(13) + --<--
    'Second Name : ' + @lastName

SELECT @text
```

Output -

```
First Name : 11
Second Name : 22
```

Comment: Using only CHAR(13) gives strange result when writing result to console. Lines seem to overwrite each other. Adding CHAR(10) (=line feed) after the CHAR(13) fixes this problem.

Answer (score 11):

You may use

```
CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Comment: this does not work for some reason in online versions i.e. Hackerrank

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
DECLARE @firstName NVARCHAR(50)
    ,   @lastName NVARCHAR(50)
    ,   @text NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

SELECT @text = 'First Name : ' + @firstName + @NewLineChar + 'Second Name : ' + @lastName
PRINT @Text
```

Answer (score 2):

`CHAR(13)` will show the text in new line, when you switch to `Result to text`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `CHAR(13)` between your two string.

```
SELECT @text nvarchar(MAX) = 'First Name : ' + @firstName + CHAR(13) + ' Second Name : ' + @secondName
```