# Is there any way to use newline character in SQL server Select Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> The question is based on SQL Server not about ssrs NEW Line

i had Already go through the stackoverflow below links related to this topic

1)[New line in Sql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085662/new-line-in-sql-query)

2)[New line in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528471/new-line-in-sql-server)

3)[New line in Sql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085662/new-line-in-sql-query)

But i didn't get any answer for my situation

My problem is that i need a newline character in select query results

Example : i have a string like below

```
Today is Friday Yesterday is Thursday
```

and when I select this varchar value from my table I need it to to appear like this in my SSRS report:

```
Today is Friday
Yesterday is Thursday
```

I have tried many ways like

```
select 'Today is Friday' +char(13)+'Yesterday is Thursday'
```

but it gives me a result  `Today is Friday Yesterday is Thursday`

but when i use print insted of select then i got the results what i want 
But i cannot use print in my scenario because i need this result in aother query and that query i have used for ssrs reporting purpose

I know i can split this query and show it in two rows but in my case i can't do something like that too because the results i have used in many select querys.

i don't know  it is possible in Sqlserver, if it is possible then 
 please help me to solve my problem

Edit : please help me if it is possible in Grid Mode rather than text mode

Comment: What about char(13)+char(10)?

Comment: @xQbert same result i had tried that too but no use it works with print but does not work with select

Comment: char(13)+char(10) works if you display the results as text (`Ctrl+T`) instead of in a grid (`Ctrl+D`)

Comment: Where is the display occurring?

Comment: @xQbert I need to display it in a ssrs report

Comment: So maybe... Double click on the filed value to open place holder property window and under general tab Change Markup type from "none-plain text only" to "HTML -Interpret HTML tags as Style" or... http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/11/12/creating-a-line-break-within-an-ssrs-expression.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS how to add in New line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306328/ssrs-how-to-add-in-new-line)

Comment: @TabAlleman who told you my question is about ssrs new line ? i had already mention my question clearly then how it would be ssrs new line ??

Comment: Your comment above to xQbert:   "I need to display it in a ssrs report"   Did I misinterpret that?  I believe you have a basic misunderstanding.   There is no such thing as a newline in SQL Server.  There are only characters which will render as a newline in the program that you use to view them.   If you are interested in how the text displays in SSRS, then you have an SSRS question.  Not a SQL Server question.   SQL Server is only storing information, not displaying it.

Comment: @TabAlleman it is my final purpose what in ssrs i can't do anything because i had already written an algoritham for generating string based on some cases any only inside that algorithm i can understand which one will be come under newline . so i can't do anything in ssrs. so i need a solution in sql server it self

Comment: I think you're saying you've coded yourself into a corner and are unwilling to consider starting over with a different approach.  I'm afraid you have to.   There is NOTHING you can do in SQL Server to return data that won't have to do something special with on the SSRS side to make it display as a new line.   There IS NO "solution in sql server itself".   Sorry.  Both Gabor and Scott have given you answers that will work.

Comment: @TabAlleman yes i am ready to take different approach. But without knowing which part need to be in new line how i can proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Since when you use `print` you do see the line break, it seems to me like the problem is that you execute this query in SSMS, while the result is displayed as a grid.
Try changing the display result to text and you will see the line break just like you see it when you use `print` instead of `select`.
Btw, I think you better use `char(13)+char(10)` as xQbert suggested in the comments.

Comment: yes in text mode it will be works fine but how can i use this text mode in ssrs reporting when i return the query results i think it will be return as grid

Comment: I've actually never had to deal with SSRS in 10 years of working with sql server, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in Managment Studio this works fine:

```
select 'Today is Friday' +char(13)+'Yesterday is Thursday'
```

If result to grid is selected in Managment Studio then it is printed in one line becouse this works in that way. If you copy and paste it from grid to notepad you will see it works. Try checking result to Text. It works to.

Comment: yes in text mode it will be works fine but how can i use this text mode in ssrs reporting when i return the query results i think it will be return as grid

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with SSRS, but maybe this link is helpful for You:
[SSRS how to add in New line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306328/ssrs-how-to-add-in-new-line)

This suggest to use expression, like this:

```
=Replace(Field!Names.Value, ",", VbCrLf)
```

Comment: yes it is possible but i can't split it using any special characters because sometimes the string contains special characters so when i split it in ssrs then may be the logic fails so i need to split it inside the sql function for generating the string

Comment: Can't You use some special delimiter? Then You can replace this special string with VbCrLf.

Comment: what will do if string contain  special delimiters

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display the new line in an SSRS report, try using `<br />` instead of `CHAR(10)` - and make sure to set the control that contains this text to allow HTML.

[image]

Comment: Please read my question it is not related to ssrs. i need an sql server solution

Comment: your comment an hour ago says - "yes in text mode it will be works fine but how can i use this text mode in ssrs reporting when i return the query results i think it will be return as grid" - my example shows how to make it work for SSRS. How things display in SSMS is completely separate from SSRS.

Comment: yes i had commented like that . and still the problem remains same because only inside my string generating function i can find which all strings are come under newline. i know i can show strings in new line in ssrs but how can i know which one will be come under new line ? my string contain special characters letters anything so i can't split it